# Laravel4: how to access a static function of a binding

Tags: php, laravel

how can I get access to a static function of a binding? Is it even possible?

**what works so far is:**

in a serviceProvider boot() method:

```
$this->app->bind('MyInterface', function(){

                return new MyImplementation();
            });
```

or via the reflection thing in laravel (works same way):

```
$this->app->bind('MyInterface', 'MyImplementation');
```

and then in my business logic:

```
$interfaceObject = app::make('MyInterface');
$interfaceObject->create();
```

**what NOT works:**

if the create() function is static in the bound implementation class, then I can`t do:

MyInterface::create();

how do i do this? A facade should not be the solution since facades map "fake"-static methods against a real object, right?

Answer (score 0):

An understanding of statics is really what you need here. Static functions are really not good when you start delving into OOP. In Laravel 3 it was possible to use statics on the majority of classes as the static facades were provided mainly via `__callStatic` magic methods as well as some well designed implementations such as `Eloquent`. It also made sense to build helpers onto models using statics, though even Taylor Otwell described in the docs that separation of concerns was a better strategy, creating repositories, services and entities rather than a generic 'model'.

When you start looking at inheritance, specifically dependency injection, statics are much harder to work with as they tightly couple code that use your concrete classes. If you think about it, a concrete implementation wouldn't really want static methods bound to it for this very reason. A possible workaround would be to create a new facade to the concrete implementation that uses statics, still not good OOP practice, though it does provide you with a looser pattern to work with. It still feels like it'd be very much an anti-pattern in my eyes.

That said, you can build statics into your interfaces.

```
interface AnInterface {

    public static function takeArgAndReturnSomething($arg);

}
```

Obviously the concrete class that implements this interface would require such a static, and as such Laravel should be able to manage a static call via the inversion of control bindings.

In all, I'd try and stick away from using statics in these cases.

Comment: lol just wrote a long answer but cant answer my own questions for 8 hours, and omment too long, forgor to copy text